# Avoid redundant LINQ computations during mapping of properties using AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

Is it possible to somehow avoid redundant computations of `src.Purchases.MaxBy(p => p.PurchaseDate)` in case below?

```
cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastPurchaseProduct, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Purchases.MaxBy(p => p.PurchaseDate).Product))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastPurchaseQuantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Purchases.MaxBy(p => p.PurchaseDate).Quantity))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastPurchaseTotalAmount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Purchases.MaxBy(p => p.PurchaseDate).TotalAmount));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to remove redundancy by using `IncludeMembers`.
Thanks to [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) for advice.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .IncludeMembers(src => src.Purchases.MaxBy(p => p.PurchaseDate));
cfg.CreateMap<Purchase, CustomerDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastPurchaseProduct, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastPurchaseQuantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastPurchaseTotalAmount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TotalAmount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to `Customer` a `LastPurchase` property

```
[NotMapped]
public Purchase LastPurchase => _lastPurchase ??= Purchases.MaxBy(p => p.PurchaseDate);
```

And then all you need is `CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();`. If you cannot modify `Customer`, you can use `IncludeMembers`.

Comment: Another option is `ProjectTo` with `IncludeMembers`.